# How to make a div to increase width and height by clicking a button?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a button to make a div appear and also increase its height and width I got how to make the div increase in width but how do i get it to increase in height do i need another function like the one i have below for the height? And also how to add the button function in here.

Please help I am pretty new to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#box").click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "+=1250px"
        });
    });

    $("#box").click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '-=1250px'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another function:

```
   $("#box").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "+=1250px",
            height: "1250px"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use commas to separate properties in animate

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#box").click(function() {
          $(this).animate({
        width: "+=1250px",
        height: '-=250px'
           });
          });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, you have 2 handlers registered for the click event - both of them will get triggered for every click triggering both animations.

Instead what you need is a single handler which according to the widened state will either widen the element or shrink it to default state.

Try

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#box").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this), widened = $this.data('widened')
        $this.stop(true, true).animate({
            width: (widened ? '-' : '+' ) + "=1250px"
        });
        $this.data('widened', !widened)
    });   
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gCfzx/)